# Olympiad geometry question.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Let $ABC$ be an equilateral triangle.

$D$ is on $BC$ and $BAD$ angle is $20^{\circ}$.

Also let $I_1$, $I_2$ be the inner centers of triangle $ABD$, $ACD$ respectively.

$E$ is a point making the triangle $I_1I_2B$ be equilateral
($D$ and $E$ are on the opposite side of the line $I_1I_2$.

Then what is the angle $ADE$?

This is my question and I tried to find $4$ cyclic points or something like that, but I have no idea.

Please help me.

Comment: Try tackle analogical problems from Prasolov's geometry problem book(vol.I). If you REALLY got stuck, I will post solution.

Comment: Remember about spirit of olympiad question: you must REALLY approach this problem on your own and AS DEEP AS POSSIBLE on the condition that you have appropriate prelimnary background in terms of proper machinery.

Comment: @MIT I tried what I have but i don't know how to use the conditions in the problem... I know that you can think of me not trying hard but I got stuck for not short time.. I'm really got stucked. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer to this nice geometry problem...
Here is a picture of the given geometric situation, together with auxiliary points (which will be introduce one by one in the sequel):

[image: stackexchange question 2217815]

The problems gives the value $20^\circ$ for the angle
$$
x=\widehat{BAD}\ .
$$
It is convenient to introduce also the notation
$$
y=\widehat{DAC}\ ,
$$
so that $x+y=60^\circ$.
Let us work in a slightly more general case, and let $x$ be any angle (between $0^\circ$ and $30^\circ$). We will show the equality instead of $\overset?=$ below:
$$
30^\circ-x\overset?=\widehat{ADE}\ .
$$
So for the given angle, $x=20^\circ$ we expect the answer
$10^\circ=30^\circ-20^\circ=\widehat{ADE}$.

Here is one more picture for the case $x=14^\circ$, which avoids some coincidences compared to the above $20^\circ$ case:

[image: generalization stackexchange question 2217815 equilateral triangle]

---

The quadrilateral $ACDI_1$ is cyclic, because its angles in $D$,
$80^\circ+50^\circ$, and $A$, $40^\circ+10^\circ$, add to $180^\circ$.
In the general case we add $(120^\circ -y)+\frac 12(120^\circ -x)$ and
$\frac 12x+y$.
Denote the corresponding circle by $(1)$.

The quadrilateral $ABDI_2$ is cyclic, because its angles in $D$, $120^\circ+40^\circ$, and $A$, $20^\circ+20^\circ$, add to $180^\circ$.
In the general case we have also the above computation, with $x,y$ exchanged.
Denote the corresponding circle by $(2)$.

---

Let $J_1$ be the intersection $DI_2\cap BI_1$. Then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\widehat{I_1J_1D} &=
\widehat{BJ_1D} =
180^\circ- \widehat{J_1BD} - \widehat{J_1DB}
\\
&=
180^\circ- 30^\circ - (120^\circ-x) -\frac 12(120^\circ-y)
=
\frac 12x=
\widehat{I_1AD}
\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
so $J_1$ is also on the circle $(1)=(AI_1D)$.

And
$
\widehat{I_1DJ_1}
=\widehat{I_1DI_2}
=
90^\circ
$
shows that the segment $I_1J_1$ is a diameter of $(1)$.

Let $J_2$ be the intersection $DI_1\cap CI_2$. Then:
$$
\widehat{I_2J_2D} =
\widehat{I_2AD}
\ ,
$$
same argument (with $x,y$ exchanged),
so $J_2$ is also on the circle $(2)=(AI_2D)$. And since
$
\widehat{I_2DJ_2}
=\widehat{I_2DI_1}
=
90^\circ
$
the segment $I_2J_2$ is a diameter of $(2)$.

---

Let $L_1,L_2$ be the centers of the circle $(1)$, and respectively $2$.
Then
$$\widehat{AL_1D} =2\widehat{ABD}=120^\circ=2\widehat{AI_1D}\ ,$$
so $L_1$ is on the circle $(1)$. Similarly:
$$\widehat{AL_2D} =2\widehat{ACD}=120^\circ=2\widehat{AI_2D}\ ,$$
so $L_2$ is on the circle $(2)$.

Also, taking a look at the quadrilateral $AL_1DL_2$, it has perpendicular diagonals, the two triangles $\Delta AL_1D$, $\Delta AL_2D$ "building it" are isosceles, same basis, same opposed angle, $120^\circ$, so it is a rhombus. So the circles $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal (congruent), same radius, and $\Delta AL_1L_2$, $\Delta DL_1L_2$ are equilateral.

---

Let us show now $J_1L_1\perp AI_2$.
First of all, $J_1L_1$ is the angle bisector of
$\widehat{AJ_1I_2}=\widehat{AJ_1D}$ since $L_1$ is the mid point of the
$120^\circ$-arc
$\overset \frown{AD}$. So
$\widehat{AJ_1L_1}=30^\circ$. We also take a look at the $A$-angle
$\widehat{I_2AJ_1}$. Cut it in two angles using $AC$. One angle is $y/2$. The other corresponds to the arc
$\overset \frown{J_1C}$, so it is $\widehat{J_1DC}=(120-y)/2$. Putting all together, the needed $A$-angle is $60^\circ$.
This gives the wanted perpendicularity.
And moreover, $J_1L_1$ is the side bisector of $AI_2$.

In a similar fashion,
$J_2L_2\perp AI_1$, and moreover $J_2L_2$ is the side bisector of $AI_1$.
Consider now the circumcenter of $\Delta AI_1I_2$. It is $J_1L_1\cap J_2L_2$, the intersection of the side bisectors of the two sides, and the angle built with $I_1,I_2$ is twice $\widehat{I_1AI_2}=\frac 12x+\frac12y=\frac 12(x+y)=30^\circ$. So this circumcenter is the main actor from the exercise, it is $E$, making $\Delta EI_1I_2$ equilateral:
$$
E=J_1L_1\cap J_2L_2\ ,
\qquad\text{ and }
\ EA=EI_1=EI_2=I_1I_2\ .
$$

---

---

Let $F$ be now the point of intersection of the lines $J_2EL_2$ and
$AD$.
[image: stackexchange question 2217815 auxiliary point]
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
2\widehat{EFD}
&=
\overset{\frown}{AL_2} +
\underbrace{
\overset{\frown}{DBJ_2} +
\overset{\frown}{DI_2} }_{180^\circ} -
\overset{\frown}{DI_2}
=
2\widehat{ABL_2}+180^\circ-
2\widehat{DAI_2}
=
60^\circ + 180^\circ - y\ ,\text{ so}
\\
\widehat{EFD} &= 120^\circ -\frac y2\ .
\\[2mm]
\widehat{EL_1D} &= 
 \widehat{EL_1I_2} + \widehat{I_2L_1D}
=
 \widehat{J_1L_1C} + 2\widehat{I_2J_2D}
=
 \widehat{J_1DC} + 2\widehat{I_2AD}
\\
&=\frac 12(120^\circ -y) 
+ 2\cdot\frac y2=60^\circ +\frac y2\ .\qquad\text{ This gives:}
\\[2mm]
180^\circ &= \widehat{EFD} + \widehat{EL_1D} \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
So the quadrilateral $EFDL_1$ is cyclic.

---

In a similar manner to the construction of $F=J_2EL_2\cap AD$, consider the point
$G=J_1EL_1\cap AD$. The same argument gives $EGDL_2$ is cyclic, and the measure of the angle bigger $90^\circ$
built in $G$ by the lines $AD$ and $J_1EL_1$ is
$120^\circ -\frac x2$.

[image: stackexchange question 2217815 second auxiliary point]

So we know the angles in $\Delta EFG$. Things are depending on the position of $D$. We assume as in the pictures
$x\le y$. (Else switch $B$ and $C$ to get them.) Then $\widehat{EGF}=\widehat{EGD}$ is the supplement of
$120^\circ -\frac x2$, so it is $60^\circ+\frac x2$. And $\widehat{EFG}$ is the supplement of
$120^\circ -\frac y2$, so it is $60^\circ+\frac y2$. This gives:
$$
\begin{aligned}
  \widehat{FEG} &=180^\circ-\left(60^\circ +\frac x2+   60^\circ +\frac y2\right)=60^\circ -\frac 12(x+y)=30^\circ\ ,\\
  \widehat{L_1EL_2} &=\widehat{L_1EF} =180^\circ- \widehat{FEG} =150^\circ\ .\text{ Compare this information with:}\\
  \widehat{L_1DL_2} &=60^\circ\text{ and $\Delta L_1DL_2$ equilateral.}
\end{aligned}
$$
This implies that $E$ is a point on the circle centered in $D$ passing through $L_1,L_2$. So:
$$
\begin{aligned}
  \widehat{L_1DE}
  &= 2\widehat{L_1L_2E} = 2\widehat{L_1L_2A} - 2\widehat{EL_2A}
    = 120^\circ - 2\widehat{J_2L_2A}
  \\
  &=120^\circ - 2\widehat{J_2DA}=120^\circ - \widehat{BDA} = \widehat{BAD}=x\ .
  \\
  &\qquad\qquad\text{ This gives:}
  \\
  \widehat{EDA}
  &= \widehat{L_1DA} - \widehat{L_1DE} = 30^\circ -x\ .  
\end{aligned}
$$
We have computed the required angle.

$$\square$$

Knowing this, we immediately get
$$
ED\perp\ BC\ .
$$

---

---

Putting all together, and collecting some *bonus* properties, that follow from what we know, we can state as a bonus:

**Proposition:**
Let $\Delta ABC$ be equilateral. Let $D$ be a point on $BC$. Consider $I_1,I_2$ the incenters of
$\Delta ABD$, and respectively $\Delta ACD$. Denote by $x,y$ the measure of the angles
$\widehat{BAD}$, $\widehat{DAC}$, $x+y=60^\circ$.

**Then:**

- $ABDI_2$ is cyclic, denote by $2$ the circumcircle, and let $L_1$ be the corresponding circumcenter.
- $ACDI_1$ is cyclic, denote by $1$ the circumcircle, and let $L_2$ be the corresponding circumcenter.
- Construct also $J_1=BI_1\cap DI_2$, and $J_2=CI_2\cap DI_1$. Then all points with index $1$ are on the circle $1$, centered in $L_2$
  and all points with index $2$ are on the circle $2$, centered in $L_1$:
  $$
  \begin{aligned}
    \odot(L_2) &= \odot(AL_1I_1DCJ_1)\ ,\\
    \odot(L_1) &= \odot(AL_2I_2DBJ_2)\ .
  \end{aligned}
  $$

Let further $E,F,G$ be the points $E=L_1J_1\cap L_2J_2$, $F=AD\cap L_2J_2$, $G=AD\cap L_1J_1$.

**Then:**

- $E$ is the point making $\Delta EI_1I_2$ equilateral. It is uniquely characterized
  by this property, after requiring to be situated in the same half-plane delimited by the line $I_1I_2$ as $A$.
  Let $E'$ be "the other point", so $\Delta E'I_1I_2$ is equilateral. ($E'$ and $E$ are reflected to each other w.r.t. $I_1I_2$.
- Here is a list of equilateral triangles in the given setting:
  $$
  \Delta ABC\ ;\
  \Delta AI_2J_1\ ,\
  \Delta AI_1J_2\ ;\
  \Delta AL_1L_2\ ,\
  \Delta DL_1L_2\ ;\
  \Delta EI_1I_2\ ,\
  \Delta E'I_1I_2\ .
  $$
- The point $E$ is on the perpedicular in $D$ on $BC$, and
  the point $E'$ is on the perpedicular in $A$ on $BC$.
  In particular, the angle $\widehat{EDA}$ can be computed in terms of $x,y$, it is
  $30^\circ -x$.

Here is a final picture for the above situation:

[image: stackexchange question 2217815 bonus ferma toricelli point]

We have the following bonus proof for the location of $E'$.
Consider the (outer)
[Fermat-Torricelli point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point)
for the triangle $\Delta AI_1I_2$.
The three equilateral triangles to be constructed on the sides are
$\Delta AI_2J_1$,
$\Delta AI_1J_2$,
$\Delta I_1I_2E'$,
so the three lines are concurrent: $AE'$, $I_1J_1=BI_1J_1$, $I_2J_2=CI_2J_2$. The last two lines are
the medians / heights / bisectors from $B$, $C$, so they intersect in the center $O$ of $\Delta ABC$, so $A,O,E'$ are colinear.

$\square$